# Angular Lexi Error

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor

This should be easy for someone familiar with the .net framework UI. I'm getting familiar but would appreciate any suggestions.

I have the following in my .cshtml:

```
  @{
     var mappedContacts = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme, "/_images/contacts"));

var initialize = "initContacts(" + mappedContacts + ")";
}
```

On the same page with Angular:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SelectUserController" id="account-group-widget" data-ng-init="@Html.Raw(initialize)">
```

In controller :

```
 $scope.initContacts = function (data) {
                return data;
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
initialize(C:\O\Themes_images\contacts)
```

be

```
initialize('C:\O\Themes_images\contacts')
```

And check if '\' should be '\' in the string.

In Angular code the data parameter is just a string and no contact data will magically appear.

Comment: Fixed that issue but now get the value of data as: C:OThemes_imagescontacts